# regex to split text to blocks

Tags: regex, textblock

I have a text with repeating blocks separated by a specific expression. How can I  capture these blocks in between the separator lines ?

Look at this [example](https://regex101.com/r/y1gNuB/). Block separator would be `Information:` and I would like to get back the text blocks in between them, like :

1:

```
Block 1
blahblah blah
```

2:

```
Block 2
blahblah blah
```

3:

```
Block 3
a much
longer
blahblahblah
```

Comment: Change it a little bit `(Information:.*)([\s\S]*?)(?=Information|\z)` or try `Information:.*((?:(?!^Information:)[\s\S])*)`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/VN1Z2f/1

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly in regex tester but unfortunately not with Python. Don't know what's wrong...

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/sVVmnX

Comment: Finally I managed to get it work, thank you.

Answer (score -2):

See first comment, it works :

(Information:.*)([\s\S]*?)(?=Information|\z) or try Information:.*((?:(?!^Information:)[\s\S])*)